# Devise authentication error when entering site's root first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, before-filter

When user enters our web site's root or logs out, Devise authentication displays "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing" the first time. After page reload this message disappears.

Root of our web site is set to controller which has:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

**We need this controller to be the root.** How to eliminate this message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did not find the solution better than defining

```
unauthenticated: ''
```

in /config/locales/devise.en.yml file.

Comment: Assuming you have defined a container to show your flash messages, this would still show that empty container, and if you've had to style that, those styles would show with no text inside the container.

Comment: The comment by @KyleShevlin is correct. You should check for the presence of the alert text before rendering your flash message, e.g.
    `<% unless alert.blank? %>
      # render your notice / alert here
    <% end %>`

Answer (score 8):

The correct solution would be to set an authenticated block as noted in the official wiki: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages

```
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'home#index', as: :authenticated_root
  end
  root to: redirect('/users/sign_in')
```

The scoped `authenticated` block will only be called once they are logged in, so you can happily direct users to a controller of your choice. In the example it redirects them to the sign in page when unauthenticated, but this could be any action in your routes.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to get rid of the message on just the index? If so you can just do something like this:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
```

You can add other actions to the array as well.

Note this won't call `authenticate_user!` on the specified actions, so make sure the user doesn't need to be authenticated for the given actions!

Comment: I must say that also works ":only" to specify what actions are protected.

Comment: I do not want the "index" method be out of Devise's control. I just want to suppress this message.

Comment: you will have to modify the 'authenticate_user!' method directly to not show the message on the index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have encapsulated your devise error messages as shown below.

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

You can add the following CSS code to your index view file for the root controller.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .notice, .alert { visibility: hidden; }
</style>
```

This should hide the error messages from root of your website.

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario where all of your pages (except login, signup, etc) are protected against `before_action :authenticate_user!`, I'd override Devise's `SessionController` as so:

`app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    if flash[:alert] == unauthenticated_message
      flash.delete(:alert) unless requested_protected_page?
    end
    super
  end

  private

  def requested_protected_page?
    session[:user_return_to] != root_path
  end

  def unauthenticated_message
    I18n.t('devise.failure.unauthenticated')
  end
end
```

And then tell your `config/routes.rb` file to use that overridden controller:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: :sessions,
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may create a separate action in your controller, just to resolve whether user is logged in or not and then redirect to desired place.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :root

  def index
  end

  def root
    flash.keep
    redirect_to current_user ? welcome_index_path : new_user_session_path
  end
end
```

This should work, of course you should have in your ApplicationController

```
before_filer: authenticate_user!
```

and in routes root configured to welcome#root